# proving properties for $ \mathbb{Z} [ \sqrt{-6} ] $

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let be  $$R=  \mathbb{Z} [ \sqrt{-6} ]= \{a+b \sqrt{-6} | a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \} $$

I want to prove following properties from a book:

a) Any Divisor of $2$ is either a unit or associated to $2$. And also any divisor of $\sqrt{-6} $ is either a unit or associated to $\sqrt{-6} $

b)
Find Elements $x,y \in R $ so that $ \sqrt{-6} \nmid x  $ and $ \sqrt{-6} \nmid y   $ but  $ \sqrt{-6} \mid xy  $

c) $1$ is the $\gcd$ of $2$ and $ \sqrt{-6} $ but there don't exist $a,b \in R $ so that
$ 2a + \sqrt{-6} b =1 $

__

$ a|b \leftrightarrow an=b $ , $ n \in \mathbb{Z} $

$a$ and $b$ associated $ \leftrightarrow $ if there exists a $\epsilon$, so that $ b=a\epsilon $ $\leftrightarrow $ $ b \mid a   $ & $ a \mid b $

I dont know what elements I can take from $ R$..
I appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Elements of $R$ have the form $a+b\sqrt{-6}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers. You can take any such element.

Comment: so of $ N(a+b \sqrt{-6})= a^2 +6b^2 $ ?

Comment: For the first one you can use the norm. The norm of $2$ is just $2$ so you need to prove the only choice for $N(a+\sqrt{-6}b) = 2$ is being $2$ or any associate element with $2$. Because if $\alpha \mid \beta $ then $N(\alpha) \mid N(\beta)$

Comment: Is the norm of $2$ equal to $2$ or $4$ here?  Formula for $N$ seems to give $4$.

Answer (score 1):

For (b), $n(1\pm\sqrt{-6})$ is not divisible by $\sqrt{-6}$ except where $n$ is a multiple of $6$, but consider the product $(n(1+\sqrt{-6}))\cdot(m(1-\sqrt{-6}))$ when $n$ is a multiple of $2$ and $m$ is a multiple of $3$.

We get this type of example whenever (the magnitude of) the radicand is composite.